# Dynamically change an element's top position based on height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three divs that are set to popup on li:hover using CSS. I want these divs to hover at the same level above their parent li regardless of the height of their content. In order to do so, I'm trying to use jquery to calculate the div's height, then set a negative top value equal to the height of the div. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var pHeight = $('footer ul ul').height(); //Get height of footer popup
var nHeight = pHeight + "px"; //Calculate new top position based on footer popup height

        $('footer ul ul').css({ //Change top position to equal height of footer popup
            'top' : "-nHeight",
    });
});
</script>
```

Firebug keeps telling me that there was an error parsing the value for top and the declaration was dropped. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`'top' : "-nHeight",`

to

`'top' : "-" + nHeight`

JavaScript does not parse variables inside of strings. I've also removed the `,` since it's redundant and it will produce an error in IE.

Comment: Beautiful! I had a feeling the syntax was wrong, but I'm new to Jquery so I didn't know how to fix it. One more question: how do I get it to calculate the actual height of the div, not the one in the CSS? I'd hoped using height() would accomplish that, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with jQuery, you had issues with your JavaScript code. And it was not a syntax issue :) Anways, open a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the quotes to use the variable, otherwise it's trying to parse the literal string `"-nHeight"` as a number:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pHeight = $('footer ul ul').height();
  var nHeight = pHeight;    
  $('footer ul ul').css({
     'top' : -nHeight
  });
});
</script>
```

Or, the more compact version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {   
  $('footer ul ul').css({ top: -$('footer ul ul').height() });
});
</script>
```

Comment: And also remove the comma after the "-nHeight" as some browsers will not like that.

Comment: @Jan - it's a number coming from `.height()` @Shurdoof -  good catch, updated.

Comment: Oh, I've missed that you removed `+ "px`. But now you are missing a unit, so it won't work also :)

Comment: @Jan - sure it will, jQuery normalizes this, you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mpSgx/

Comment: Hmm cool. Last time I was doing something like that I had all sorts of issues :) Guess they've fixed them.

Comment: @Jan - if you do `elem.style.top` directly *then* you need a unit, but jQuery has normalized that as long as I can remember, the default unit being pixels.